# How to install and enable Firefox extensions using bash script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to install & enable a series of Firefox add-ons, for a singe profile, without user input, using a bash script. It is a matter of editing a config file in the user's profile folder, as copying an entire, manually installed folder worked.

Any online resources I could find are extremely outdated.

Just downloading the .xpi files into `~/.mozilla/firefox/*123abc.profilename/extensions` does install the add-ons, but requires user input to enable.

`user_pref("extensions.webextensions.ExtensionStorageIDB.migrated.*extensionid*", true);` is inserted into prefs.js by manual enabling, but doesn't enable the addon itseld

`extenstions.json` [1] & `extension-settings.json` also have no effect.

`extension-preferences.json` is only observed to be affected by allowing addons to run in private windows.

Thank you in advance.

##### Corrections:

[1] My Testing indicates that `extenstion.json` is what i'm looking for, but I am not yet sure what needs to be modified as it has no white space, making it hard to read. Will edit with any updates.